# How to resolve error on importing Creator Kit RPG in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm starting a project in Unity using the "Creator Kit - RPG" package, and I've encountered these errors that I can't resolve.
The error appears straight up from import :

1.
"Assets\Creator Kit - RPG\Scripts\Tiles\Isometric Rule Tile\Editor\IsometricRuleTileEditor.cs(8,26): error CS0433: The type 'IsometricRuleTile' exists in both 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'"

2. "Assets\Creator Kit - RPG\Scripts\Tiles\Isometric Rule Tile\Editor\IsometricRuleTileEditor.cs(19,32): error CS0115: 'IsometricRuleTileEditor.RuleMatrixOnGUI(RuleTile, Rect, RuleTile.TilingRule)': no suitable method found to override"
3. "Assets\Creator Kit - RPG\Scripts\Tiles\Isometric Rule Tile\Editor\IsometricRuleTileEditor.cs(72,32): error CS0507: 'IsometricRuleTileEditor.ContainsMousePosition(Rect)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'RuleTileEditor.ContainsMousePosition(Rect)'"

   It appears that the first error is related to a name conflict between two classes named "IsometricRuleTile" from different libraries: "Assembly-CSharp" and "Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras".
   Regarding the second error, it seems to involve a missing implementation of the "RuleMatrixOnGUI" method in the "IsometricRuleTileEditor" class.
   Finally, the third error indicates a problem with overriding the "ContainsMousePosition(Rect)" method in the "IsometricRuleTileEditor" class.

Has anyone encountered similar issues or can suggest possible solutions for these three errors?

I really appreciate your help!

Thank you,

I tried remove the conflict of the file commenting the file but it still didn't fix the error